# c++ flashing when rendering directx elements over a win32 camCaptureWindow

Tags: c++, winapi, directx, render

I am creating an application that uses directx to render images over a win32 capture window from a webcam, but I'm the window is flashing every other frame. (This seems to be coming from directx clearing the screen every frame, as the flashing color is the same as the clear color)

Is there any way I can fix this problem? (I wasn't able to figure out how to provide a camera feed without using win32)

And here's my code for the project:

Windows.cpp:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <vfw.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include "Game.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include "Mouse.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

static KeyboardServer kServ;
static MouseServer mServ;

char szAppName [] = TEXT("Webcam");
HWND camhwnd;
HDC hdc ;
HDC hdcMem;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HBITMAP hbm;
RECT rc;

//WinMain -- Main Window
int WINAPI WinMain ( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow ) {

    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = szAppName;

    RegisterClass (&wc);


    hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName,szAppName,WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE,0,0,1920,1080,0,0,hInstance,0);


    ShowWindow (hwnd,SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow (hwnd);

    ShowWindow(camhwnd,SW_SHOW);
    SendMessage(camhwnd,WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT,0,0);
    SendMessage(camhwnd, WM_CAP_SET_SCALE, true , 0);
    SendMessage(camhwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 66, 0);
    SendMessage(camhwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, true , 0);



    Game theGame( hwnd,kServ,mServ );


    while( msg.message != WM_QUIT ) {
        if( PeekMessage( &msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE ) ) {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }
        else {
            theGame.Go();
        }
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

//Main Window Procedure WindowProc
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    switch (message) {
        case WM_CREATE: {

            camhwnd = capCreateCaptureWindow ("camera window", WS_CHILD , 0, 0, 1920, 1080, hwnd, 0);
            SendMessage(camhwnd,WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT,0,0);
            SendMessage(camhwnd,WM_CAP_DLG_VIDEOSOURCE,0,0);

            break;

        }

        case WM_DESTROY: {
            SendMessage(camhwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, 0, 0);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A portion of Game.cpp:

```
void Game::Go()
{
    gfx.BeginFrame();
    ComposeFrame();
    gfx.EndFrame();
}
```

And finally, a piece of the D3DGraphics.cpp:

```
D3DGraphics::D3DGraphics( HWND hWnd )
{
    HRESULT result;

    backRect.pBits = NULL;

    pDirect3D = Direct3DCreate9( D3D_SDK_VERSION );
    assert( pDirect3D != NULL );

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
    ZeroMemory( &d3dpp,sizeof( d3dpp ) );
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_UNKNOWN;
    d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_ONE;
    d3dpp.Flags = D3DPRESENTFLAG_LOCKABLE_BACKBUFFER;

    result = pDirect3D->CreateDevice( D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,hWnd,
        D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING | D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE,&d3dpp,&pDevice );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    result = pDevice->GetBackBuffer( 0,0,D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO,&pBackBuffer );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );
}

void D3DGraphics::BeginFrame()
{
    HRESULT result;

    result = pDevice->Clear( 0,NULL,D3DCLEAR_TARGET,D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,255),0.0f,0 );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    result = pBackBuffer->LockRect( &backRect,NULL,NULL );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );
}

void D3DGraphics::EndFrame()
{
    HRESULT result;

    result = pBackBuffer->UnlockRect();
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    result = pDevice->Present( NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding `WS_CLIPSIBLINGS` and `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` to the main window. More info about these window styles [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).